# React with Redux - unable to bind action to parent

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to the Redux pattern i'm having some trouble linking an action in a separate JS file to it's parent component. Here is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import playSample from './sampleActions/clickToPlay';

class SamplesInnerLrg extends Component {  
    render() {
         return <div>
   {
     this.props.samples.map((sample) => {
        return (
                <div key={sample.id} className="sample-comp-lge">
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-header">
                        <span className="sample-comp-lge-Name">{sample.sampleName}</span>
                        <span className="sample-comp-lge-id">{sample.sampleFamily}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-audio" ref={sample.id} onClick={() => this.bind.playSample(sample)}>
                        <audio preload="auto" id="myAudio">
                              <source src={sample.soundSource} type="audio/wav" />
                        </audio>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-owner">{sample.uploader}</div>
                </div>
            )
        })
     }
   </div>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        samples:state.samples
    };
} 

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({playSample:playSample},dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(SamplesInnerLrg);
```

Specifically I am trying to have an onClick action on this line that will call a function in an imported file (clickToPlay.js):

```
<div className="sample-comp-lge-audio" ref={sample.id} onClick={() => this.bind.playSample(sample)}>
```

The clickToPlay file looks like so:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export const playSample = (sample) => {
    console.log(sample);

        return {
            type:"Play_Sample_clicked",
            payload:sample
        }
    };
```

the error i'm getting on click is Cannot read property 'playSample' of undefined. I'm guessing I have bound the action to the component correcly but I can't tell why?

EDIT:

Here is my index.js file as requested:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { createStore,compose } from 'redux';
import allReducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(allReducers,compose(
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    ));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't exporting 'playSample' as the default export, you have two ways to reslove this:

You can do:

`import { playSample } from './sampleActions/clickToPlay';`

or

you can change `export const playSample` to `const playSample` Then add `export default playSample` at the end of your file.

Another note I want to mention about this line:

```
return bindActionCreators({playSample:playSample},dispatch)
```

I don't see why you are doing `{playSample:playSample}` just change it to `playSample`. ES6 allows you to eliminate key if it's the same as value, this is called **object literal property value shorthand**.

Comment: thanks but still throws the same error on click.I believe having export const playSample is just a quicker way to export if there's only one export in the file. Thanks for the tip about ES6 allowing to eliminate key though!

Comment: I see @DannyDyer. Updated my answer

Comment: I actually tried that a few mins ago and got this error: this2.props.playSample is not a function

Comment: You have a 2 after `this`

Comment: yes I know this is what the console spits out, i dont actually have that in the code

Comment: Hmmm, Can you post your `index.js` file? did you wrap `<Provider  />` around your `Router` or highest level component?

Comment: posted above, yes wrapped it around the highest level component

Comment: figured it out btw. see answer